# De Jure and De Facto Girlfriend

Tags: meaning, grammar

The message of the sentence I want to create is, **“She is my girlfriend in practice and by title.”**

However, I want to substitute the word “in practice” with “de facto” and the word “by title” with “de jure.” This would create a sentence like, **“She is my de facto and de jure girlfriend.”**

Is this correct grammatically? I understand that de jure is more commonly used in legal matters like state affairs. However, could it be used to signify a two-way agreement of a title between two parties (my girlfriend and I) rather than simply what is written by law?

Comment: What do you mean by "signify a two-way agreement of a title between two parties"? That sounds very much like legal jargon. Any number of words can be used to represent an agreement between two people. Most people would find the description you just gave as unusual. Also, what do you mean specifically by *title*? Most people who are dating don't do so according to any kind of title.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. What I mean by that is that both people (the girlfriend and I) agree that we are in a relationship. This means that she is agreeig that I am her boyfriend and I am agreeing that she is my girlfriend. We both agree and the titles “boyfriend” and “girlfriend” are official between us and promulgated among relevant people like friends are relatives.

Comment: Ah! So you are not using *title* to mean a deed or some other piece of paper, but just as the agreed-upon word to describe the relationship. Even if you could use *de jure* in that sense, the legal language would be strange outside of a legal context. It might be fine, as a kind of joke, if used among lawyers who all speak the same language … (*De facto* is somewhat more common that *de jure*, but only relatively speaking.)

Comment: Aww yeah I was thinking that it would be a bit confusing for most people (maybe even to lawyers). Maybe the sentence should instead be, “She is my de facto and titular girlfriend.”

Comment: Quotes (or airquotes for speech) would work for the sense of title: *She is my de facto "girlfriend."*